# Finding current user

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a VBS script to copy files on another computer without manually entering their username into my script. Where it says USER in the script is where I need to put the current user.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FolderExists("C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\")) Then
   FSO.CopyFile "V.VBS", "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
   FSO.CopyFile "M.mp3", "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\"
Else
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to obtain the name of the current user, for instance

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
username = net.UserName
```

or by expanding the `%USERNAME%` environment variable

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
username = sh.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERNAME%")
```

Once you have the usrename you can build your path string like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
profile = fso.BuildPath("C:\Users", username)
startup = fso.BuildPath(profile, "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
```

---

Since you're working with a subfolder of the user's `AppData` folder you could also expand the `%APPDATA%` variable instead of the `%USERNAME%` variable:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

appdata = fso.BuildPath("C:\Users", sh.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%APPDATA%"))
startup = fso.BuildPath(appdata, "Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
```

---

Another option would be to read the startup folder location from the registry and expand the environment variable(s) in the returned path string:

```
regpath = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Startup"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
startup = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(sh.RegRead(regpath))
```

Comment: FSO.CopyFile "V.VBS", "startup" isn't working for copying how would I do that?

Comment: You would use the variable `startup` instead of the string `"startup"`.

Comment: Fixed it all that was wrong besides the "startup" was a missing backslash thank you!