# Getting the user using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I need to find a way to get the current user of the system and put it in the address.

Right now I am using this script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim User
User = "User"
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Users\" & User & "\Documents\Test\M2.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I am using it to run a batch file without showing. Right now to change the user I have to change the variable myself. Is there a way to make it automatic?

Comment: Automatic how? What do you want this script to do?

Comment: By automatic I meant that I dont have to change the "User" Variable everytime I change the system...This Script will be run on a USB and I want it to be able to change the "User" depending on what user it is on. Because I need it to access the Documents file and as you most probably know the directory for that is C:\Users\"Depending on the User"\Documents. I need it to be able to change that field top whatever the user is.

Answer (score 2):

```
Msgbox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
```

The correct way is to ask the system where is My Documents. Users can move them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of obtaining the username of the currently logged-in user, for example:

- expanding the environment variable `%USERNAME%`:

  ```
  Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  User = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
  ```
- via the `UserName` property of a `WshNetwork` object:

  ```
  Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  User = net.UserName
  ```
- from the `Win32_ComputerSystem` WMI class:

  ```
  Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
  For o In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
      User = o.UserName
  Next
  ```
- via ADSI:

  ```
  Set sys = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
  User = sys.UserName
  ```

For a more complete list see [this overview](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_network_names_user.php) compiled by Rob van der Woude.

Comment: [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948057/692942) you have given before.